# Basic authentication for elasticsearch pod running in kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, nginx, kubernetes, kibana

We need to create basic (username/password) authentication for elasticsearch and kibana oss (Apache license) running into our kubernetes clusters.
We have multi-cloud installations in AWS (EKS), Google cloud (GKE), on-premise installations and we plan to use Azure.

I think about nginx reverse proxy with basic authentication running as sidecar container in each elasticsearch/kibana pod. This is will be a simple and known solution.

The question is: What is be the right solution in k8s cluster? What we can take from an infinite number of solutions for easy maintenance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you are using `nginx ingress controller` you can add basic auth like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kibana
  namespace: kibana
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    # type of authentication
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
    # name of the secret that contains the user/password definitions
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: my-secret-basic-auth
    # message to display with an appropriate context why the authentication is required
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: 'Authentication Required - kibana-admin'
  ...
  ...
```

The `my-secret-basic-auth` have to be created with `htpasswd`:

```
$ htpasswd -c auth foo
New password: <bar>
New password:
Re-type new password:
Adding password for user foo
```

Then you need to create the secret:

```
$ kubectl create secret generic my-secret-basic-auth --from-file=auth
secret "my-secret-basic-auth" created
```

That's simple and easy to maintain but you will be attach to `nginx ingress controller` forever.

Comment: Please keep in mind that the elasticsearch pod and service may still be accessible from other pods running in your kubernetes cluster.